# How to Format Highcharts dataLabels Decimal Points

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/YKLUQ/1/) and let me know how I can format the dataLabels to be display only with two decimal numbers?

Here is the numver formats which I have in the series

```
 series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.554555, 6.34345559, 9.5555, 14.5555, 18.4333433, 21.5555, 25.2, 26.5333333, 23.33333, 18.23243543, 13.776565669, 9.65454656]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
```

and I would like to present them like 7.55 , 6.34, 9.55 . Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to combine the `dataLabels` [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.dataLabels.formatter) and [Highcharts.numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat):

```
...
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
    }
}
...
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/YKLUQ/2/)

Comment: But with your solution a number like 1450 display 1450.00

Comment: You could check for decimals in the `this.y` value before formatting (otherwise just pass back `this.y`). @Core972

Comment: many thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for. In my case I'm showing data that can be in thousands/millions/billions so I'm doing this in this function and adding 1 decimal for millions and billions but not under. So, thanks again. – For those you needs to do the same, I've posted my code below'

Answer (score 26):

I would simply add a the format option to data labels as follows:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '{point.y:,.2f}'
}
```

It's the simple way of doing it without having to define a function using formatter.

extra:

The comma after the colon makes sure that a number like 1450.33333 displays as 1,450.33 which is nice also.

Comment: But with your solution a number like 1450 display 1450.00

Comment: Yes, which may or may not be preferred. In most cases it's better to display the .00 if the rest of the numbers show decimals: 1451.11, 1543.12, 1450 looks ugly. It may be the desirable effect though in which case you're going to have to use the `formatter` and manually parse values.

Comment: You must use `Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {thousandsSep: ','}});` to get a comma, otherwise the thousands separator defaults to a space.   https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang

Answer (score 3):

In case someone wants to go "further", I'm showing data that can be 10^1 to 10^9 so I'm converting them and showing the unit afterwards.

Remember, Highcarts deals only with integers so if you want to add units (and not in the YAxis because of multiple units) you can give it in the source data but you have to format them afterwards:

```
column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    // Display only values greater than 0.
                    // In other words, the 0 will never be displayed.
                    if (this.y > 0) {
                        if (this.y >= Math.pow(10, 9))
                        {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y /Math.pow(10, 9) , 1) + " mias";
                        }
                        else if (this.y >= Math.pow(10, 6))
                        {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y /Math.pow(10, 6) , 1) + " mios";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                        }
                    }
                },
```

mias : stands for "milliards" (french translation of billiards)
mios : stands for "millions" (french translation of millions)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in the comments you wanted to **not display trailing zeroes**.

This was the simplest solution I was able to muster:

```
...
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return parseFloat(this.y.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
    }
}
...
```

If you don't want the number to end up with a comma-separator (depending on locale) remove the .toLocaleString().

**Sidenote:** Unfortunately using format (instead of formatter and a js func like we do above) is limited to a subset of ***float*** formatting conventions from the C library function sprintf, as indicated [here on highcharts website](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting). That library has [the code g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field) that would automatically do this for us but unfortunately it is not implemented in Highcharts  :(, i.e. format: '{point.y:,.2g}' does not work.